# How do you get rid of all scrollbars in an iframe in Safari/webkit?

Tags: css, iframe, safari, webkit

I've tried scrolling="no" and overflow:hidden; Nothing seems to make the vertical scrollbar go away in iframes on Safari/webkit. Anyone know?

Comment: Looks like I was setting an overflow setting in my css already which was tripping me up. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use overflow:hidden on the included body.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on this? Do you mean something like `iframe body { overflow:hidden }` ?

Comment: I meant that you should edit the included page so that the `body` has `overflow: hidden;`. If you don't have the ability to edit the inner page, I don't think you can do anything.

Comment: overflow:hidden worked for everything but IE7.  For that, add scroll="no" to the body tag of the included document in addition to the overflow:hidden style.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I add `overflow:hidden;` to the `html` tag instead of `body`?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, and it's a bug. See the W3C for expected behaviour.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_scrolling